# Formula has more levels of nesting that allowed. can it be shortened, or another approach?

Tags: excel, nested

I wish to have data entered in column O of several worksheets flow through to the master, called '2.calibration sheet'.

i have tried to use the formula below but received above error message:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'ACM Teams'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'AGM DRs'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Business Trans'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Cust Resp'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,DCMs!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Dirs DRs'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,Hubs!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Ops Dev'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Peters DRs DRs'!A:O,15,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,'Sales & Marketing'!A:O,15,0),
   IFERROR(VLOOKUP('2. Calibration Sheet'!A2,SLP!A:O,15,0),"Not Found")
```

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: In Excel 2007 up to 64 levels of nesting are allowed - you aren't breaking that so make sure you don't have "compatability mode" set, i.e. ensure you save as an "xlsx" file and the above should work [otherwise 7 levels of nesting as per Excel 2003 will apply]

Comment: I thought you can only nest 7 levels of IFs.

Comment: I was using compatibility mode, but saved as .xlsx and encountered the same problem before asking the question.      Could be due to the IFs.  is there a smarter way around that?

Comment: what version of excel are you using, what is the original format of the file?

Comment: Its Excel 2010, but originally built in compatibility mode.  'Saved as' to xlsx, but still got the same message.